# "Is to be expected" in the sentence

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to say "No one knows what sort of weather is to be expected" or will it be better if I say "No one knows what kind of weather to expect"?If the first variant is wrong, why?

Comment: [or is it better to say] Both are right.

Comment: @Lambie, why is not "will it be better"?

Comment: @Boyep Because when you make a general statement in English, you use the simple present.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are grammatical, but the second ("... to expect") is more common and should be preferred. Most modern style guides recommend avoiding the passive voice ("is to be expected") when possible. In this case the active voice version is clearer and simpler/shorter/more concise than the alternative.